# PHP Trying to get property of a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$sql = "select customer-name, customer-city from customer where customer-name in (select distinct customer-name from depositor, account where depositor.account-number=account.account-number and account.branch-name='Downtown')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { //LINE 18
  // output result in each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Name: ". $row['customer-name']. " " . $row["customer-city"] . "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

The error I get:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in line 18
```

I tried using an array and that did not work either, I got the same error.

Comment: Notice that there is a line in your code that prints "ERROR" when `$result` is falsy.  You might want to dig into why `$result` isn't what you think it should be and how you can surface a better error message.

Comment: There are less than 18 lines. If you give the line number, it would help.

Comment: @FrançoisB. this is line 18 `if ($result->num_rows > 0)     //LINE 18`

Answer (score 0):

In the PDO call of query (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php), you can see the following:
`PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or false on failure.`

It means that if the query fails, you keep only a `false` instead of the `PDOStatement` object.

```
$sql = "select customer-name, customer-city from customer where customer-name in (select distinct customer-name from depositor, account where depositor.account-number=account.account-number and account.branch-name='Downtown')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result == false) {
  echo "Query failed";
} else if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output result in each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Name: ". $row['customer-name']. " " . $row["customer-city"] . "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```